# Entity Framework 6.x - Unable to create a constant value of type "ClassName". Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

.Net 4.5.x using EF 6.x

I have a method that is calling an overridden `ClassName.Equals()` method. I needed a values equality comparison, not a reference one.

I get this error however in my exception: `Unable to create a constant value of type 'ClassName'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.`

After googling around, I came across this post regarding using partial classes: 
[SO/How to override equals on a object created by an Entity Data Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472441/how-to-override-equals-on-a-object-created-by-an-entity-data-model)

However, I get the same error when separating out `ClassName.Equals()` to a partial class in it's own separate file.

In case this is relevant, the .Equals is getting called in a LINQ `.Any()`:

`public bool Exists(ClassName c) => ClassNameContext.Any(x => x.Equals(c));`

Is EF just unable to translate my .Equals override into SQL? Is there a viable solution? Will I need to actually define how to run the equals comparison in the .Exists method?

Comment: EF cannot translate unknown code to SQL. You should provide the explicit comparison expression to the `Queryable` method, e.g `Any(x => x.Prop1 == c.Prop1 && x.Prop2 == c.Prop2 && ....)`

Comment: @IvanStoev - that's what I was afraid of then. Bummer.